# Accessing child elements of XML via php

Tags: php, xml

So I have this XML :-

```
<ApiResponse Status="OK">
    <Errors/>
    <Warnings/>  
    <RequestedCommand>namecheap.domains.getlist</RequestedCommand>
    <CommandResponse Type="namecheap.domains.getList"></CommandResponse>
    <Server>PHX01SBAPI02</Server>
    <GMTTimeDifference>--7:00</GMTTimeDifference>
    <ExecutionTime>0.07</ExecutionTime>
</ApiResponse>
```

How can I access the value of "**Status**" in **ApiResponse**?

I tried :-

```
foreach($xml->ApiResponse->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

But it throws this error :-

```
main(): Node no longer exists
```

Comment: `$xml` will contain the root element, which is `ApiResponse`, so you don't need to access that. Try: `$xml->attributes()`. If you just want `OK`, you can just do: `echo (string) $xml->attributes();`, since it only have one attribute.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson

Got that running, stuck at another thing. Updated the question.

Comment: **Don't change your original question.** Make a new question, ask in a comment (if it is a pure follow up question). When a question is asked, it belongs to the community. Alos, changing it will make all existing comments and potential answers useless for future visitors. I rolled back your changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try simplexml_load_string..

```
$xmlArray = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json = json_encode($xmlArray);
$xmlFormated = json_decode($json,TRUE);

print_r($xmlFormated);
```